# react-lazy-load for grid of images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have grid of images in my react application. I am using sprites to show the images for the div grid. Each 10 div uses one single url to show the thumbnail. There are around 16000 thumbs I have to show. I am trying to use react-lazy-load. This is what I have tried

```
<LazyLoad height={200} offset={100}>
                                    <div className="thumb">
                                        <div className="thumb-inner">
                                            <div className="image" style={{backgroundImage: `url('${sprite.url}')`, backgroundPositionX: -((i % 10) *100) + "px", backgroundPositionY: -(82 * Math.floor(i/10))}}></div>
                                            <div className="timestamp">01:15:12</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </LazyLoad>
```

This is not performing as expected. I expect this to call image url when the divs corresponding to that are in viewport. Currently all the image urls are getting called together at once.

Comment: Can you place your problem in https://codesandbox.io/s/ for us to understand better?

Comment: unfortunately there is a lot of css involved. It would be hard for me to make a sandbox code. I can provide all the information here whatever is required

Comment: Without https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it may be difficult for anyone to help

Answer (score 0):

The height is equal to zero before the photo is downloaded. So you have to define height for the parent of the photo.

```
links.map(item => {
return (<div className="your-grid-container">
   <LazyLoad height={200} offset={100}>
        <div className="your-image-container">
            <img link={item}/>
        </div>
    </LazyLoad
</div>)
})


.your-grid-container{
   display : grid;
}

.your-image-contaner{
   height : 200px; // bingoooo, now  grid container can calculate correctly
}
```

[Demo](https://www.bilgintenteci.com/kumas/docril) - 
Watch network console for better understanding.